# "He intends leaving tomorrow"

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

> He intends to leave tomorrow. (1)
>
> He intends leaving tomorrow.  (2)
>
> (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

CGEL says there’s no discernible difference between the two, yet I imagine some difference from the ‘be+~ing’ meaning. This presents a plan / intention and implies near future. Although the adjunct, tomorrow, weakens the meaning of the plan or near future, (2) still has the meaning of your intentionality or volition, I guess. Can it be the proper difference?

Comment: It seems to me CGEL correctly says there's "no discernible difference between the two", so I don't see how ELL can meaningfully supply answers justifying your (mistaken) impression that there ***is*** a difference.

Comment: I agree with CGEL. But I have to say that a gerund complement--or indeed any frankly nominal complement--falls very old-fashioned on my ear. I have a dim recollection of seeing a corpus study on this -- I'll try to track it down. ... More generally, I've never seen ANY treatment which convincingly drew semantic distinctions between the various English futurives. For now I continue to believe that it is prosody and discourse context which governs these uses.

Comment: As both Stoney and Fumble say it's correct, I'll accept that it is, but *He intends leaving tomorrow* sounds completely incorrect to me. I would have told you in no uncertain terms it was wrong, had I not read their comments first. So I would at least say it is not idiomatic, and that you should use *to leave* instead.

Comment: http://www.grammaring.com/to-infinitive-or-gerund-begin-start-continue-cease-dread-intend-love

Comment: From [Google Ngrams,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+intends+making%2CHe+intends+to+make&year_start=1750&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20intends%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20intends%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0) it appears that the *"he intends leaving"* construction has fallen into disuse over the last 50 years. I expect that in another 50 years, it will be considered ungrammatical. If people had generally perceived a difference, I expect that both constructions would have remained in use. I agree with @WendiKidd: use *"to leave"*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Interesting link! I'm fine with all their examples except *intend contacting*. That one sounds just as wrong to me as the example in the question does.

Comment: An important note. CGEL argues that there is no difference **in meaning**.

Comment: BNC: intend* VVG 2.2 per million, intend* TO0 63.2 per million; COCA: intend* vvg 26, intend* to 4489. The infinitive after "intend" is much more common in both BrE and AmE.

Comment: In that situation I'd say, "He intends *on* leaving" or "He intends to leave"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the hot topics among English-language linguists is the ‘Great Complement Shift’—the apparently well-established fact that for about four hundred years speakers have been drifting away from infinitive non-finite complements and toward gerund non-finite complements. You'll find a comfortably brief discussion in 3.4 of [this draft](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/projects/verb-phrase/LateModernEnglishSyntaxDraftJune2011.pdf) of a forthcoming book chapter.

It’s important to note, however, that this trend has **no predictive value at all**. There are many verbs which exhibit the opposite tendency, away from gerunds and towards infinitives. [This paper](http://www.hf.uio.no/ilos/forskning/grupper/Corpus_Linguistics_Group/ThomasEgan.html), for instance, aptly titled ‘Swimming against the tide of the Great Complement Shift’, identifies *prefer* and *continue* as two such verbs.

*Intend* is another such. The Comments to your question show how distasteful WendiKidd, Mari-LouA and I find the use with gerund complements, and our instinct is corroborated by the corpus data cited by Alex B. The Google NGram which Peter Shor links suggests, and the one [below](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+intends+making%2CHe+intends+to+make&year_start=1750&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20intends%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20intends%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0) appears to confirm, that use with the gerund  has never been as common as that with the infinitive, and has steadily become less common over the past century.

[image]

Use with the gerund is basically a 19th-century alternative: perfectly correct, but unusual today.

As for a distinction in meaning, I think it very unlikely, unless you suppose that 19th-century writers were two or three times more likely to have firm short-term intentions than their modern counterparts.

When you're dealing with an individual verb, the distinct between infinitive or gerund or *FOR .. TO ..* or *that* complementation is certainly meaningful. But I'm very dubious about claims that such distinctions have any **global** significance; and even if such significance could be shown, it would still be irrelevant to individual cases, which should always be suspected of Swimming Against the Tide.